# Any standard abstraction like this? (aka. Guess The Structure)

Tags: haskell

I came up with the following structure while refactoring a hobby project. I'm wondering if it matches, or can be tweaked to match, some existing abstraction / structure. I started reading up on `Applicative`, `Functor` and `Arrow`s, but couldn't make the connection, and I don't have more ideas. So, the minimal useful example:

```
-- trivial struct for this minimal example
data T = T { n :: Int, s :: String }

-- for any type `a`, there's exactly one way to update a `T`
class Gen a where
  gen :: a -> T -> T

-- helpers to compose `a`-s into a (T -> T)
(.>) :: (Gen a) => (T -> T) -> a -> (T -> T)
l .> x = l . (gen x)

(<.>) :: (Gen a, Gen b) => a -> b -> T -> T
l <.> r = (gen l) . (gen r)

-- For this example, let's say an Int is used to update a T by adding to its `n`
instance Gen Int where
  gen x t = t { n = (n t) + x }

-- and a Char is prepended to its `s`
instance Gen Char where
  gen c t = t { s = c : (s t) }

-- I can now express things like this easily
appendFooAndAdd3 = 'F' <.> 'o' .> 'o' .> (3::Int)
```

The actual code, in case more context is useful: https://github.com/abesto/hsircd/blob/cc8e9e33617f61ef9417b9476856a9fdc6bc4948/src/Server.hs#L81-L135

If you find some structure that can be used here, I'd be extra grateful if you could explain how you came to the conclusion. I imagine I could learn a lot from it.

**Edit**: to clarify what I'm asking: can this be implemented by using some existing abstraction? `Applicative` and `Functor` are examples of what I mean, but they don't seem to match this case. If yes, how did you come to the structure?

Comment: So.... what's your question?  It's not very clear at all what you want help with.

Comment: Added an edit to clarify it.

Comment: Well, usually things like Applicatives and Functors are useful when working with polymorphic containers, but your type is just a plain old data type with no polymorphism, there might not be much you can abstract here.  You could use `FlexibleContexts` and `MultiParamTypeClasses` to write it as `class Gen a t where gen :: a -> t -> t` (this looks suspiciously like a generalized cons type) and then `appendFooAndAdd3 :: (Gen Char t, Gen Int t) => t -> t` with the same definition, then it can be used with more types than just `T`, but you might run into overlapping instance problems.

Comment: Perhaps [lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens).

Comment: I just wanted to add, I asked a similar question a few months back (though my thought process hadn't advanced as far as yours) and Lens is definitely what you want. If you want to understand the theory behind lenses then this video is amazing: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cefnmjtAolY and if you just want a quick start check out https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/a-little-lens-starter-tutorial or the accepted answer to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25954467/are-there-any-useful-abstractions-for-haskells-record-syntax/25955062#25955062

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I had a look through the documentation for [`lens`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) to figure out how to do this. It seems this is the idiomatic way:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
import Control.Lens
import Control.Lens.TH

data T = T
    { _n :: Int
    , _s :: String
    } deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)

makeLenses ''T

appendFooAndAdd3 = (s <>~ "Foo") . (n +~ 3)
```

You'll notice that things are not *quite* as implicit in your approach: in `s <>~ "Foo"`, one must name the field `s` and the operation `<>` one wants to perform, and similarly in `n +~ 3`. Nevertheless this may be seen as a strength, as it is fairly rare that there is just one way to modify a `T`.

In this case, I think the Pythonism "explicit is better than implicit" applies.